# How does Fortran handle optional arguments and strings?

Tags: fortran

I have the following code:

```
program test
    implicit none
    call test_routine("TEST")
    call test_routine("TEST",.true.)
end program

subroutine test_routine(var1,var2)
    implicit none
    character(*)      :: var1
    logical, optional :: var2

    write(*,*) len_trim(var1)
    write(*,*) var1
end
```

The output looks like this:

```
           0

           4
 TEST
```

Why does this occur? I would expect the function to behave the same whether the `var2` argument is present or not.

Comment: You need explicit interface. We should have a duplicate.